# Add Calendar Activity iOS

Tags: html, ios

When I booked a ticket via a major airline I got the opportunity to add the flight to my calendar by clicking a button. The title, a description and the departure time were available if you added it to your calendar.

How are you able to do this? I would like to have a similar function to my website.

My booking was made via the airlines website and no app was used.

Answer (score -1):

Are you familiar with jQuery UI? They have a datepicker functionality already built. From the information you've provided, this may be an excellent option for you. It requires a little bit of scripting and CSS knowledge to modify and edit, but it's very well documented and you can get the hang of it pretty quick. There's also lots of YouTube tutorials for jQuery UI available to help if you need it. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: The question is about how is the site able to add an appointment to the iOS calendar, not about a date picker.